# I have a problem with baking - "No active UV layer found"

Tags: mesh

As you can see in my screenshot im having trouble baking a texture for Ambient Occlusion. I  already added a new image and smart uv unwrapped my low poly mesh "rock_lp". It is the second one i selected, so its the active one. The other one is the high poly version. When i try to bake, I get the error "No active UV layer found in the object rock_hp". What does this mean? Is there something i forgot to do?

[image]

PS: I already added a new image after doing retopology on the low poly mesh so that was ok I believe.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, try check if your low poly object has UV map or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your high poly one is the one active, which explain the error you are getting about the UVs for your high poly mesh. Just reselect them and you should be fine.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I reselected but now I get another error which is “no image found”. I have only unwrapped the low poly, i have made a new image for that as you can see. Do I do have to make a UV image for my high poly mesh?

Comment: No, the high poly never need to have UVs when baking. You need to create an image texture node (don't connect it to anything, just leave it there) in the low poly material, and create a new blank image with that node (best to watch a baking tutorial if you are confused), make sure it's selected and try baking again. Right now what's happening is that your baked data doesn't know where to go, you need to assign an image to it first, this is one of Blender's weirdness.

Comment: It does sound a bit confusing but il have a go, thanks! At least I know what the problem is now.